# How do I remove the comma from the date in the sparkline tooltip?

Tags: r, shiny, sparklines

I'd like to remove the comma from the date in the sparkling tooltip, but I need to keep it in the value.
I don't fully understand the [jQuery Sparkline](https://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#tooltips) formatting.

[Sparkling tooltip example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULLxq.png)

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(

  htmlwidgets::getDependency('sparkline'),

  DT::dataTableOutput("table")

)

server <- function(input, output) {

    raw_data <- data.frame(date = 2000:2021,
                     value = sample(100:500, 22))

  data <- raw_data %>%
    # Create the sparkline
    summarise("value" = sparkline::spk_chr(c(value),
                                xvalues = date,
                                tooltipFormat = '{{x}}: {{y}}'))

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

    cb <- htmlwidgets::JS('function(){debugger;HTMLWidgets.staticRender();}')

    DT::datatable(data = data,
              escape = FALSE,
              options = list(drawCallback = cb))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As defined [here](https://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#interactive), you can set `numberDigitGroupSep` to empty string:

```
data <- raw_data %>%
    # Create the sparkline
    summarise(
        "value" = sparkline::spk_chr(
            c(value),
            numberDigitGroupSep = "",
            xvalues = date,
            tooltipFormat = '{{x}}: {{y}}'
        )
    )
```

Comment: Ah great, thank you! Is there a way to only apply this to the xvalues?